# SSH connection to a router from Server

Tags: ssh

I tried creating SSH connection to a router . SSH works fine . 
The following scenario was tried .

Created ip address to an interface in router and added SSH configurations to this interface . Made sure that the execution server and the router are in the same subnet . Did a SSH from the execution server to the router . Works fine .

I want the SSH connection to remain even after the interface in the router goes down . Is it possible

Comment: If the destination disappears (i.e. your router interface goes down) there's nothing left for your `ssh` connection to talk to. You might be able to do something about automatic reconnection with `autossh`. Possibly.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Doing that would make no sense at all.

It would be like asking for the light to stay on when you flip off the switch.  The only way to do that would be to invalidate the switch.